# What are advantages of using multiple instances of OHS 11g webserver?

Tags: oracle, apache, oracle10g, webserver

Few days ago I came to know about the OHS feature i.e can create multiple instances. I am wondering,if using multiple instances of OHS webserver increases the performance of the Webserver.

Is there any advantage, other than less server space use for using multiple instances of OHS?

Where this feature of OHS is used?

TIA
Anil

Comment: No answers .. its sad. Still waiting for the pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that main advantage is to eliminate single point of failure situation. If one of them somehow crashes, others continue running.

http://books.google.lv/books?id=GZFfNa4ZvpoC&pg=PA256&lpg=PA256&dq=multiple+instances+of+OHS&source=bl&ots=VFwuacPEOr&sig=eknoCdmXa2bUzvCL-segzM2Ud6o&hl=lv&ei=5K5VSqTgKoGqnQO2lpTdCQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2

Comment: Thanks a lot jva. This give answer to my question.